# Windows Defender found "Backdoor.Win32/IRCbot.gen!M" what to do next?

Tags: windows-vista, virus, spyware, windows-defender

The History of Windows-Defender on a vista home premium lists 3 times this software. The fist time "sucessfully" and two times "ignored".
There is no button for any action, like remove, delete or something other. What is to do as next step?

A following second fast-scan runs through without a new entry - is now everything fine?

Comment: Get Microsoft Security Essentials, which is a vast improvement of Defender, and run the scan again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-SpyWare and Anti-Virus are what you need; I like these ones a lot:

F-Prot Anti-Virus
  http://www.f-prot.com/

MalWare Bytes
  http://www.malwarebytes.org/

SpyBot - Search & Destroy
  http://security.kolla.de/

Sometimes an active SpyWare and/or Virus wlil prevent a full disinfection.  If this happens to you, then you'll need to run the scan/clean processes from a clean machine on your hard drive as a secondary drive.  If you need more information about this, please ask.